# Produce/keep static AES key for all the applications

Tags: encryption, random, openssl, aes, secret-key

Whenever any application(browser, thick client application) is requesting to generate an AES key, I would like to supply a static key to that application.

Is there any way to do this in Linux or windows?

Answer (score 0):

There is **not** an universal way of generating **AES keys** that applications needs to adhere to.

**Forcing a static key** on an **arbitrary application** ought to be hard/impossible if the application is secure - and would be a case by case activity.